# how to create a ~/bin folder in all user's home location?

Tags: linux, directory, users, home

We want to create a personal bin directory in all user's home location.

Is there any way to create a ~/bin folder by default, when we create users for the first time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are going to create the users with `adduser`, then check `/etc/adduser.conf`. In that file you have a mention to the skeleton for each new user, by default `/etc/skel`.

If you create `/etc/skel/bin` then that folder is going to be created for each new user you add with `adduser`.

Comment: I suggest using both this method and my method. This method will make sure it happens for all new users, my method fixes it for all users that are already created.

Answer (score 2):

You can do in the shell like this:

`cd /home && for user in * ; do sudo mkdir $user/bin && sudo chown $user $user/bin ; done`

But be warned ! I'm making a couple of *(very reasonable)* assumptions here:

- You probably don't really want **all** users but only the users with a home-directory that is a subdir in `/home` (A lot of system services are bound to "special" users like ntp, mail, www-data, ...)
- Every subdir in `/home` is probably the homedir of a user with the same name
- You want the owner of every `bin`-dir to be the same as the user of which the home-dir is. If on your system every user has a group with the same name and you also want to set the group of `bin` correctly then change `chown $user` to `chown $user:$user`

Comment: You could limit the potential damage by checking for (say) `.bashrc` or some other file that is also delivered by `/etc/skel`.

Comment: Good idea, this makes the assumptions even more reasonable. But this can also lead to overconfidence... Regular users don't always keep the files in `/etc/skel`. For example: Most distro's install bash, but users can change and remove `.bashrc`. (I myself always use `zsh`, I don't remove `.bashrc` but others might choose to do this...). This is brings us to the root of the problem: The more you test if the user is 'real' the more confident but also over-confident you become...

Comment: I think the only way to be really sure who is a 'real' user is to log it whenever you create a 'real' new user and to manually check which old users are 'real'.

Comment: In that situation you could fall back just to using `skel`. You could try all sorts of heuristics (`last`, for example) but ultimately it's difficult to be totally and absolutely certain one can differentiate real user accounts from system accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a script that calls `adduser` or `useradd` and then creates the `~/bin` folder.

Example (untested):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
useradd $!@
mkdir $!@/bin
```

Then put it in `/usr/local/bin` and `chmod` it to be executable.

```
chmod uog+x my_user_add
mv my_user_add /usr/local/bin
```